# Symfony 3 - Assetic dump works on dev but doesn't work on prod

Tags: php, css, symfony, assetic

I'm new with symfony 3 and I'm trying to develop a web app application. To combine my css and js files, I've installed assetic bundle and I'm using it on dev mode, It works fine and I haven’t any problems.

Then when I try to test my web app on production mode, css and js are not complete and the website doesn't work fine.

I’ve tried these two commands but nothing has changed:

- `php bin/console assetic:dump -env=prod`
- `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod`

The only way to make production work is to set `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` on app.php file, but I don't think this is the best solution.

Any ideas?

Here my code on base template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets
        'css/dist/bootstrap.css'
        'css/dist/bootstrap-grid.css'
        'css/dist/bootstrap-reboot.css'
        'css/dist/font-awesome.css'
        'css/dist/sidenav.css'
        'css/dist/head.css'
        'css/dist/main.css'
        filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled/app.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

As you can see I get my css files from `<root>/web/css/dist/*` and I dump on `<root>/web/css/compiled/app.css` the file is created on dump, But not all css are there.

Same procedure for js files.

Comment: you forgot a - before "env"  : `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod` and you have to optimize symlinks when you do your composer install by doing `composer install -o`

Comment: Can you explain to me what I've to do with composer? Only this command, or I've to use it in the future when I install something?

Comment: Did you try to install your assets too ? `php bin/console assets:install --env=prod`; Also, show us your `app/config/config.yml`

Comment: Ok I didn't run `php bin/console assets:install --env=prod` now It works fine, thanks to @tchap

Comment: Glad it helped! I made my comment into an answer so you can accept it if anyone stumbles on this issue later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install your assets too :

```
php bin/console assets:install --env=prod
```